# Using synce-install-cab in fedora to install cab file

Tags: fedora, cab, fedora20

I have Fedora 20 and want to install a .cab file. I found the proper way to do this is with synce (http://linuxmanpages.net/manpages/fedora21/man1/synce-install-cab.1.html). However when I type:

```
synce-install-cab - install .cab data.cab
```

or

```
synce-install-cab - install data.cab
```

I get the following message:

```
Enter .cab file as parameter
```

How can I install my cab file properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fedora 20 is EOL and after all the recent CVEs you certainly should update to something supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so, two things.

First, are you *sure* this is the command you want? This command is for installing software in .cab files to Windows CE devices. If you don't have that, maybe you want *cabextract* (although that won't, of course, make Windows software actually *run* on Fedora).

Second... I don't know this actual command (as I don't have a a Windows CE device), but, from the man page you linked, there's no reason to run `synce-install-cab - install .cab data.cab` —  that's not *instructions*, it's just the summary at the top of the file. The actual command seems simply to be

```
synce-install-cab data.cab
```

Comment: I ran cabextract but got: 'WARNING; found InstallShield header. This is probably an InstallShield file. Use UNSHIELD from www.synce.org to unpack it.'.  I suppose I am using wrong command. I just want to install a .dat program in fedora.

Comment: What is the program? I'm not familiar with what a `.dat` program is, other than an arbitrary data file.

Comment: What *is* the cab program? It sounds like it is Windows software, which will not just run on Fedora or any other Linux, just like it wouldn't run on a Mac. You may be able to run it with Wine — but that's not a sure thing.

Comment: Stata for Linux does not appear to be distributed in that way. See http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/unix/install-on-linux/ — I'd suggest contacting your IT support or whoever provided you with this.